# Where are the internal drain valves in a Navien 240a tankless water heater?

Tags: tankless

I have a 3 year old Navien 240a tankless water heater. A lot of water continuously flow through the condensation line even the heat exchanger is not operating. The leak can only be stopped when I close the cold water inlet. Most technician said there might be a leak in the heat exchanger. In one post with a similar issue, actually had to replace the 2 internal drain valves to fix the problem. Could anyone please point me where I can find the 2 internal drain valve? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: For those not familiar with it, it might be helpful to include the installation/owner's manual and/or a picture or two of your unit. Someone may be able to pick out the valves just by looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Take the cover off and you can see 2 translucent silicone hoses that connect from the small drain valves to the condensate drain line. One of them was leaking bad enough to cause an E037 (leak) error code on my NP240A.